# How to draw connected tubes?

Tags: modeling, draw-mode

I want to draw tubes like the blue one on the image. I was wondering if there is a tool to draw such kind of tubes? [image]

Answer (score 7):

You can begin with vertices extrusions:

[image]

Give your object a *Skin* modifier and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier (at a subdivision level of 1):

[image]

You can change the vertices radius in the *N* panel (or select the vertex and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>):

[image]

When you're good, apply the modifiers. You can then simplify the topology with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* (and tweak the parameters in the *Operator* box).